# Why I get an error request in my Ajax-Query (PHP POST)?

Tags: jquery

I get everytime an error-request if I exec my script but the email arrived:

.js:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'email.php',
            success: function () {
                alert('SUCCESS!');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('ERROR!');
            }
        });
```

.php:

```
<?php
   $from = "sender@sender.de";
   $subject = "Subject / Betreff: Test";
   $message = "Nachricht Test Test Test Nachricht";
   $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
   mail("resiver@resiever.de",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
?>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Log the error message by modifying your `error` property to: `error: function(xhr, status, error) { console.log(error); };` (or continue to use `alert` if you are unable to access the JavaScript console.

Comment: I won't get the error-message. I will get the "SUCCESS!"-alert. The application sends the email and went into the error-request and i dont know why, because he sends the mail. Then he must go into the success-request normally, or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your js with (added console.log of error)

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'email.php',
            success: function () {
                alert('SUCCESS!');
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
```

And your console will answer you the question - **why**. Its propably some obvious php error. Also make sure you havent set `500 error header` of php anywhere before ajax is executed.

Comment: I won't get the error-message. I will get the "SUCCESS!"-alert. The application sends the email and went into the error-request and i dont know why, because he sends the mail. Then he must go into the success-request normally, or not?

Answer (score 0):

YOur first mistake is defining `type : 'post'` as I know `type` parameter is must be upercase because I've been there. First step change `type : 'POST'` and if still not work try to Change this part and then check your console.log

```
error: function(e) {
    console.log(e.responseText);
}
```

Comment: The type is caseinsensitive. And the responseText is: ""... An empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I used following code and I thing it worked.

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'email.php',
    success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
});

in PHP file:

```
<?php
   $from = "sender@sender.de";
   $subject = "Subject / Betreff: Test";
   $message = "Nachricht Test Test Test Nachricht";
   $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
   if ( mail("resiver@resiever.de",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n") ) {
       echo "Success!";
   } else {
       echo "Error!";
   }
   exit;
?>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Nothing works. I think it's a issue with the server.. I think he need to long to answer..